# 3d transform in a canvas element

Tags: html, dom, css, canvas

I'm building a game with html5 game engine. I want to create something like it:
http://cubiq.org/building-a-pure-css-3d-city
It's possible by some way (javascript matrix ?) apply 3d transform in a image render by html5 canvas (without tree.js) like css3 do on a image render by DOM ?

Answer (score -1):

I have not idea. If need netrivial geometry, use script from https://github.com/Alexei03a/shapyjs . Use DOM CSS3 transform in canvas elements.

WebKit Utils for get point in transformed DOM element:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/webkitpoint
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/domwindow_additions